# Stream Writer not creating text document

Tags: c#, directory, var, streamwriter

I am creating a c# program to output a list of folders and files from a removable drive such as a USB stick or Disc to a text file.

I have a combo box (`cbo1`) which contains the drives, the start button which is suppose to create the text file and a refresh button (`btnRefresh`) which refreshes and displays what drives are available.

I'm currently working on the start button and using `StreamWriter`, but for some reason (I can't see why) it's not working.

Any idea's? If you need any other info let me know...

```
private void enumerateFiles()
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(
      @"C:\\Users\\r.samways\\Desktop\\test.txt"))
    {
        string selValue = Cbo1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        var _files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(
          selValue, 
          "*.*", 
          SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in _files)
        {
            var fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
            var _fileLength = fileinfo.Length;
            var _fileName = fileinfo.Name;
            var _fileFullname = fileinfo.FullName;
            writer.WriteLine(_fileFullname);
            {writer.Flush();}
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug it? Are there any files enumerated (maybe somethings wrong with `selValue`)?

Comment: I haven't tried debugging no, that i'm not sure and still trying to work out...

Comment: So please start debugging it. You should put a little effort in finding out the problem by yourself before asking.

Comment: I'm confused... is this the method you use? In your comment to Luk6e's answer you show a _different_ code. There you use a `searchPattern` that looks like `"."` which won't match any files. In your question you currently use `"*.*"` which should work. Please edit your answer and show the _not working code you are using_. Note that the `searchPattern` argument is _not_ used as a regex but as a file mask.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the @ at the start of your path you don't need to escape the back slash.  Try this as your path

@"C:\Users\r.samways\Desktop\test.txt"

Comment: Though you are right that no escaping is needed if OP uses `@`, that does not solve the problem. Double back slashes are simply ignored by `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: well this is what I have for the button click method:

Comment: private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _drive = (string)Cbo1.SelectedItem; //This contains the drive we're looking at (C:\ for example)

            var _files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(_drive,"*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        }

Comment: @DatCrazyGuy01 What are you filling your combo box with?

Comment: @DatCrazyGuy01 This code differs from what you showed in your question. Especially your file mask (`"."`) won't work. In your question you showed `"*.*"` which should work. Please edit your question to show the code you _are using_ that _doesn't work_.

Comment: drive E:\ which is available.

Comment: i'm not sure thats why i'm asking for advice

Comment: @DatCrazyGuy01 Let me say it different. How are you filling it? Through code like Cbo1.Items.Add("E:\"); or in the parameters of the control?

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\\Users\\r.samways\\Desktop\\test.txt",false)
```

also don't forget to close your StreamWriter when finished.

```
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining why you posted that code, what does it do and how will it solve the problem at hand. Also consider taking the time to format your answer to be easily understood by readers.